# Why Can't I Add Comments

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

I don't see any way to add a comment. Am I just not seeing it or is there some other reason for this?

Comment: As you can see, I just discovered that I can add comments, but only for my own question. Why is this?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you must have 50 reputation points in order to add comments

Answer (score 3):

You can read the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/faq) to figure out. It's a protection measure to avoid spamming.